# JavaScript: How to auto increment a counter asynchronously

Tags: javascript

I want to auto increment a counter after click without blocking the interactions with the browser. I know that I need **setTimeout** or **setInterval** , but don't know how to implement. Any help will be appreciated. 
Here is the code

**HTML**

```
<button id="start">start</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
let start= document.querySelector('#start'); 

const counter = () => {
  for(let i = 0; i<1000; i++){
  console.log(i)
 }
}

start.addEventListener("click", counter);
```

Comment: Most javascript is blocking. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36588775/are-javascript-promise-asynchronous --- although it is talking about promises

Comment: @evolutionxbox No it's not, see web workers.

Comment: "but don't know how to implement" Reading [some documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) would probably be a good start...

Comment: @JuanMendes I know of web workers, but that's not a language feature. That's a web api. Even inside a web worker JS is still single threaded.

Comment: @evolutionxbox That allows you to write non-blocking JS

Comment: ECMAScript doesn't say anything about whether it's blocking or single-threaded or anything else. Most implementations are single threaded (to some extent). In any case, this is hardly the place to discuss this, @JuanMendes, evolutionxbox...

Comment: @HereticMonkey fair point

Comment: Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191865/code-for-a-simple-javascript-countdown-timer/1191875#1191875

Comment: @evolutionxbox  thank you, I need to read more about Asynchronous functions .

Comment: @Greg so do I, so do I.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const output = document.getElementById("output");
 
function start() {
  let counter = 0;
  setInterval(() => {
    output.innerHTML = ++counter;
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<div id="output">0<div>
<button onclick="start()">Start</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set a Promise and await till the runtime.

```js
const start = document.getElementById("start");
const bar = document.getElementById("bar");
const percent = document.getElementById("percent");
const results = document.getElementById("results");

let promisseId = 0;

const counter = (n = 100) => {
  if (n > 100) {
    n = 100;
  }

  promisseId++;

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    // Here you can set a reject, (resolve, reject) the reject() must run in case your counter throws an error...
    const id = promisseId;

    let i = 1; // i is set outsite.
    const interval = setInterval(function() {
      if (i === n) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        resolve({
          i,
          id
        });
      }
      bar.value = i++;
    }, 100);
  });
};

start.addEventListener(
  "click",
  () =>
    counter(parseInt(this.percent.value)).then((res) => {
    const p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerText = `Promise ${res.id} resolved! It goes to ${res.i}%`;
    results.appendChild(p);
  })
); // console.log the "res" when its resolved! You can use another value instead of 100 at counter(100).
```

```html
<input id="bar" type="range" min="1" max="100" value="1" /> Go to <input id="percent" type="number" value="100" />% |
<button id="start">Start</button>
<p>Run it multiple times and simultaneously w/ different values, to see the magic!</p>
<div id="results"></div>
```

On the above example try Starting an 100% execution and imediatly an 10%, you will see the execution of 10% ending before the full one.

Just to make it complete, this will be a case using both, resolve and reject:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  if (yourCondition) {
    resolve('Something to return as Success');
  } else {
    reject('Something to return on Failed');
  }
});
```

Comment: @ Iago Calazans thank you very much for answer. Your answer is what  I want and very smart. But I could't run it. gives " Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'  ". Can you take a look, please?

Comment: Hey @Greg, i made it! Sorry for this little mistake!

Comment: Hey @Iago Calazans , thank you for quick response. I did it, now it doesn't throw any error, but there is no output in console.

Comment: now code runs but in the end throws this error  "Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: i is not defined"

Comment: let i must be set outsite the for to be enable outsite it. The For function in JS have it own scope! :)

Comment: Did you make it work?

Comment: Hey @Iago Calazans unfortunately not. it is not asynchronous and doesn't work on click button, check here https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-cdn-ro439?file=/src/assignment-1.js:525-559

Comment: Oh ok! On the eventListener i was calling it directly instead of using it as a callback! I fixed it, check it! It need to be () => counter() ....

Comment: Hey @Iago Calazans button works, but it is still not asynchronous , check here
https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-cdn-ro439?file=/src/index.js:602-629

Comment: @Greg i've made a few changes on your code to show you it at works! The value you pass on counter() call will be the range slide trough.

Comment: If you click on "Start" multiple times you will see it working Asyc! :)

Comment: Hey @Iago Calazans, thank you, now it works:).
Have a great day

Comment: Thanks! I think my answer is more complete then the other one on your question! hahaha