# `resolve` and `reject` functions inside a Promise's executor

Tags: javascript

Given that the client programmer both defines and uses the `resolve` function passed to the executor of a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), I naively assumed that I fully control the signature of the `resolve` function and so I can define it to take more than one arguments.

Yet the following code ([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6jdvgLqd/)) fails:

```
<html>
  <script>
   const promise = new Promise(function executor(resolve, reject) {
     setTimeout(function () {
       resolve(42, true);
       }, 1000);
   });
   promise.then(function resolveCallback(answer, howCertain) {
     console.log('callback called with arguments: ('+answer+', '+howCertain+')');
     console.log('the answer is: '+answer+'. I am '+(howCertain?'very':'not very')+' certain about that');
   });
  </script>
</html>
```

The above code actually prints on the console:

```
callback called with arguments: (42, undefined)
the answer is: 42. I am not very certain about that
```

Digging a little deeper, I wrote the below code ([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vk8es439/3)):

```
<html>
  <script>
   const promise = new Promise(function executor(resolve, reject) {
     console.log('entering executor, resolve is: ['+resolve+']'.);
     setTimeout(function () {
       console.log('about to call resolve');
       resolve(42);
       console.log('returning from resolve');       
       }, 1000);
   });
   console.log('about to call "then"');
   promise.then(function resolveCallback(answer) {
     console.log('the answer is: '+answer);
   });
  </script>
</html>
```

which actually prints the following on the console:

```
entering executor, resolve is: [function t() { [native code] }]
about to call "then"
about to call resolve
returning from resolve
the answer is: 42
```

This demonstrates a number of interesting things:

- the executor is called before the client programmer has a chance to call `then` on the promise. And yet, the `resolve` parameter in the `executor` function is not `undefined`.
- the `resolveCallback` function that is passed as argument in the call to `then` is not the same as the `resolve` function passed to the `executor`. Moreover, it is not executed synchronously (i.e. not in the same event loop run) with the `resolve` call from within the `executor` function.

The only way for Javascript to pull this off (that I can think of) is that the implementation is actually plugging some sort of "proxy" `resolve` and `reject` functions which are asynchronously linked to the actual `resolve` and `reject` functions supplied by the client programmer. This would also explain why you can't define your own signature for the `resolve` and `reject` functions: because the plumbing won't work.

Is this mental model correct or am I missing something?

Comment: "*Given that the client programmer defines the resolve function passed to the executor of a Promise*" - no, he doesn't. Where did you get that from?

Comment: @Bergi when I call `then` on the promise, don't I pass a `resolve` function of my choosing? I naively assumed that this is the same as the `resolve` function that's available inside the `executor` but I think it was a reasonable assumption to make. This experiment proved that this assumption does not hold. I am merely trying to confirm my mental model.

Comment: *"The only way for Javascript to pull this off (that I can think of) is that the implementation is actually plugging some sort of "proxy" resolve and reject functions"* - It would seem obvious to me, since the status of the Promise object also needs to be changed from "pending" to "resolved" when the `resolve` callback is invoked. Also, remember you can call `.then()` multiple times on the same promise, and all those callbacks are executed when the promise resolves, meaning they go into an internal queue inside the Promise object, and are called one by one when `resolve` is called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The client programmer defines the resolve function passed to the executor of a Promise

No, he doesn't (as your experiment confirms). The executor is called during the `new Promise` creation.

> When I call `then` on the promise, don't I pass a `resolve` function of my choosing?

No, you pass an `onResolve` listener callback, or [actually an `onFulfill`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29269515/1048572) callback.

> Is my new mental model correct?

Yes, there is more plumbing below the surface.

Indeed, the `new Promise` constructor is giving you just proxy resolver functions.

A promise contains a state machine. It is an object representing an (one!) asynchronous result. As such, you can call `.then()` as many times on the same promise object, and the callbacks will always get passed the result.

It is not a wrapper around the `executor` function, it does not call the executor as often as you call `then`. The executor is called just once, to give the *producer* access to the resolver functions (the input of the state machine). The *consumers* that call `then`, watching the output of the state machine, are completely decoupled from this - as you say, they are *asynchronously* linked.

Also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572). For your mental model, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15668353/1048572) is an easy-to-understand implementation of the `Promise` class (sans guaranteed asynchrony and error handling).