# Why does Promise treat the resolve function as returning a falsey value?

Tags: javascript, promise

The following code

```
new Promise((resolve) => {
    const v = resolve("called resolve()");
    if (!v) {
        console.log("resolve() returned a falsey value");
    }
}).then((value) => {
    console.log(value);
    return true;
});
```

outputs

```
resolve() returned a falsey value
called resolve()
```

Why did the if statement in the Promise's function body get executed even though the provided resolve function through `.then()` clearly returns `true`?

Also the if statement is clearly written after the resolve function call, why does it get executed before it finds out what the resolve function actually returns?

Comment: `resolve` is designed to return `undefined`. Is there a reason you're expecting something else?

Comment: @NicholasTower well you could use it for logic, no? Then does it mean that the resolve function in the promise and the function I passed through `.then()` are different functions?

Comment: `resolve` is a signal that the promise has completed, it is not a sink for the callback passed to `then`. Promises are push-based, not pull-based.

Comment: The then() function is where you will get the output of the promise, once its completed, and the resolve() funciton is where you will signal that the promise completed and pass the result to it.

Comment: "*even though the provided resolve function through `.then()`*" - no, a `.then()` call does not "provide" the `resolve` function to the promise executor function. The `new Promise` constructor calls that on its own, and keeps the resolution result in its state. The `.then()` function only registers an "event handler", and you can call `.then()` zero times, multiple times, before, or after the promise resolves, and it won't change the execution or the promise state. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50413583/resolve-and-reject-functions-inside-a-promises-executor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how it is designed: it returns `undefined`, always. The purpose of the resolve function is to set the promise's state to resolved, nothing more. There's no need to return a value, since there's no information that can be provided back to you. If you care about what you resolved it with (in your case, `"called resolve()"`), you can save that in a variable and use it.

```
const value = "called resolve()"
resolve(value);
if (!value) {
  // ...
}
```

> Why did the if statement in the Promise's function body get executed even though the provided resolve function through .then() clearly returns true?

The resolve function just deals with *this* promise; the one that's created by `new Promise`. It doesn't know anything about other promises, such as the one created by calling `.then` on this promise. Even if it did know about the other promises, it needs to return a value right now, and those other promises havn't resolved yet.

> Also the if statement is clearly written after the resolve function call, why does it get executed before it finds out what the resolve function actually returns?

When you call `resolve`, you set the state of the promise to resolved, and then immediately move on to the next line of code. If there are any pieces of code that have called `.then` on your promise, they will get queued up to execute, but they don't execute yet. Your synchronous code must first return, and only then does the `.then` callback execute.