# JavaScript Promise constructor

Tags: javascript

Whenever we create a new promise class, we would do something like this:

```
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve("success");
  }, 4000)
});
promise.then((result) => console.log(result));
```

So, this is my way of thinking about how things work behind:

1. `Promise` will have  a constructor of an arrow function.
2. `setTimeout` will run the `resolve('success')` function within the specified time limit, and returning a `Promise` with `resolved` state (which I think is another class because it has constructor)
3. The `then()` function will run whatever function passed on the first step (So in this case, the anonymous arrow function that returns the Promise)

First of all, why we can pass a resolve and use it as a function in `setTimeout`? I thought we haven't even declared it yet and it's not the part of the window.

Second, can someone correct my way of thinking here (so maybe can help me explaining what is going on within the process)?

Comment: 1. No, the constructor is being _passed_ an arrow function. 2. No, `setTimeout` doesn't return a promise (and the promise that `new Promise` creates is initially pending, not resolved. 3. No, it runs whatever function is passed to it, in your case the one that logs the result. And `resolve` _is_ declared, as a parameter. I'd recommend reading e.g. MDN's docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: resolve is the first argument of the new Promise callback. Change it to `new Promise((res,rej) => setTimeout(res, 4000, 'success'))` and it will work the same

Comment: `resolve` is part of the [Promise API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve). You're not passing it in or declaring it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When or who does pass resolve and reject functions to JS promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40046657/1048572) or [`resolve` and `reject` functions inside a Promise's executor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50413583/1048572)?

Comment: Are you asking for a reusable function that when given a value and a time in milliseconds will resolve that value after that time, so that you don't have to keep repeating the same code?

Answer (score 1):

> Promise will have a constructor of an arrow function.

Not sure what you mean there.

> setTimeout will run the resolve('success') function within the specified time limit, and returning a Promise with resolved state

No. Neither `setTimeout` nor `resolve` nor the arrow function that you passed to `new Promise` do return a promise.

> The `then()` function will run whatever function passed on the first step

No. The function passed to `new Promise` (know as the *executor*) is called immediately. Not from the `.then()` call. Notice that it's called even if you don't call `.then()`, or do it later only, or do it multiple times.

> why we can pass a `resolve` and use it as a function? I thought we haven't even declared it yet and it's not the part of the window.

The `new Promise` constructor creates the `resolve` and the `reject` function. They do nothing but [change the internal state of the promise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29268569/1048572), and schedule handlers that were registered on the promise object.

You might want to have a look at [this example implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15668353/1048572) or [How is a promise/defer library implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17718673/1048572).