# What this piece of JS code is doing exactly

Tags: javascript, promise

This is sample code from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

```js
function resolveAfter2Seconds(x) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(x);
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function f1() {
  var x = await resolveAfter2Seconds(10);
  console.log(x); // 10
}

f1();
```

I have few questions:

1. What is the `resolve` in the `Promise` constructor, and what `resolve(x)` do exactly?
2. What is asynchronous code? is it the call to `resolveAfter2Seconds` or just the code inside `resolveAfter2Seconds` (that is: the promise execution, while `resolveAfter2Seconds` returns immediately?

Comment: It logs "10" to the console. The basics are best to learn from tutorials and documentations, see ex. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Concepts and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: @Teemu that I know and see. My questions are about the way this code works

Comment: But that's what you've asked in the title ; ). I've updated my comment.

Comment: @VLAZ You have an excellent answer for how async/await works, a dup target. I've bookmarked it, but currently not on that machine ...

Comment: @Teemu I do? Completely honestly, I can't remember. I recall answering about some of the slightly weirder async stuff like [why assigning to a variable vs a single expression behaves differently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58614717/) but I'm not sure I've gone in detail about what OP is asking here - namely the executor function. I'm trying to find a dupe target for that.

Comment: @VLAZ I asked you to add an explanation of what blocking means, and you added it. Last autumn/winter ...

Comment: OK...I'll try to find something, in my answers about that.

Comment: @Teemu I understand `resolve` is somehow a function or supposed to be a function aka _executor function_, isn't it?  but this function is not define. Also another thing I do not understand, can a promise be used on the server side, or is it only a client side ability?

Comment: @OJNSim That might be a bit confusing, but the lines after the `await` line in `f1` is the `resolve` function. Promises are available in the latest Node.js versions too.

Comment: @VLAZ Found it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65836893/1169519

Comment: @Teemu ah, I see!  Great. However, it doesn't cover promise executors. I can't find a good dupe target for those - they are discussed in some detail in a few questions.

Comment: It's a bit ironic, that `async` and `await` were added to JS to make promises easier to understand and use. The concept hits the target when awaiting asynchronous native/library functions, but misses the target badly when a developer has to create the promise to await by himself.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. What is the `resolve` in the `Promise` constructor, and what `resolve(x)` do exactly?

The Promise constructor takes a callback function called *executor*. That executor callback [will be called with two parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624634/where-do-the-parameters-in-a-javascript-callback-function-come-from). [This call is made by the constructor itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40046657/when-or-who-does-pass-resolve-and-reject-functions-to-js-promises). Both of parameters that will be passed in are functions:

1. `resolve` - when called will *fulfill** the promise, marking it as successfully completed. The argument passed to the `resolve` function will become the value for that promise.

   The value for the promise will be passed to `.then()` callback. If the promise is `await`ed the result is the value of the promise.
2. `reject` - when called will *reject* the promise, marking it as unsuccessfully completed. The argument passed to the `reject` function will become the reason that promise was rejected.

   The reason for the rejection will be passed to `.catch()` callback. If the promise is `await`ed the reason is thrown and can be caught in a `try`/`catch` block.

*Quick note*: as with all parameters, these two can be given any name. The `resolve` and `reject` are very common ways of naming the functions.

* not necessarily true if passing another promise. If a another promise is passed, the current promise will adopt that promise's completion state. So, if `resolve` is called with a promise that is later rejected, the current promise will also be rejected.

---

The executor is then [called immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42118900/when-is-the-body-of-a-promise-executed) and the promise will be pending until either `resolve` or `reject` is called.

In your case the executor is:

```
resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(x);
  }, 2000);
}
```

Which means that `resolve` is going to be called 2 seconds later with the value for `x` making that the value for the promise.

The `await` will suspend the execution of `f1()` and resume it when promise returned by `resolveAfter2Seconds(10)` settles. The result of `await resolveAfter2Seconds(10)` is the value of the promise. Which is `10` as you can see in the log.

---

> 2. What is asynchronous code? is it the call to `resolveAfter2Seconds` or just the code inside `resolveAfter2Seconds` (that is: the promise execution, while `resolveAfter2Seconds` returns immediately?

I would say that for practical purposes, asynchronous code is anything that will finish *later* than the normal top-to-bottom execution of code:

```js
console.log(1);
console.log(2);
console.log(3);
```

```js
async function later(x) { return x; }

console.log(1);
later(2).then(value => console.log(value));
console.log(3);
```

You could definitely try to make an argument otherwise, however trying to pinpoint exactly where async code starts and ends is not very useful. It runs the risk of turning into something that resembles [Sorites paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorites_paradox). If `fn1` is not async code, then is it calling `fn2` which lies inside? Or is it `fn3` which is inside `fn2`? Etc. Hence my proposed more practical solution. If a function causes some effect to come up later than the current [run-to-completion cycle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#run-to-completion) we can say that it is asynchronous. So, any function that returns a promise (which includes all `async functions`) are asynchronous.

You can also see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65836893) which discusses various asynchronous functions more.

---

Further reading:

[What is the correct terminology for javascript promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29268569/what-is-the-correct-terminology-for-javascript-promises) - very important as it explains the fundamental concept of promises.
[`resolve` and `reject` functions inside a Promise's executor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50413583/resolve-and-reject-functions-inside-a-promises-executor)
[How is a promise/defer library implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17718673/how-is-a-promise-defer-library-implemented)
[Concept - Distilling how a promise works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668075/concept-distilling-how-a-promise-works)