# How does a callback see what it could see when it was initially encountered in the initial execution of the script?

Tags: javascript

```js
function f() {
  const color = "red";
  setTimeout(() => console.log(color), 1000); 
}

f();
```

In this code, setTimeout's callback (`() => resolve(color), 1000`) is asynchronous and is put on the macro-task queue after 1 second. When the call-stack is empty, there is a chance for the callback to be pushed onto it.

I thought to myself, when this callback is executed on this 'refreshed' call-stack, it remembers everything it had access to when it first appeared on the call-stack during 'initial execution of script'. For instance, it can access `color`. How is this possible? Is this the result of 'closures'? Does a deep-clone 'copy' of that function appear on the call-stack later and it can access all what it could access where that function was first defined? At this point I'm just guessing but I thought it a worthy question.

Comment: 1. calling `Promise.resolve` on a function will create a Promise with the value being the *function*, not the result of calling it. 2. What is "the WebAPI section"? 3. that isn't really how the call stack works. 4. There is no 'result' property. 5. There is no "main-stack". 6. If the callback is async, you don't have to wrap it in a Promise as it will return one automagically. It isn't at all clear what you are asking here, so it's difficult to understand how to answer it.

Comment: Read up on [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

Comment: Lots of articles around regarding how promises work under the hood

Comment: What do you mean by "*gets put to the WebAPI section*"?

Comment: "*When asynchronousCallback1 is executed*" - uh, in the snippet `let result = Promise.resolve(someAsynchronousCallback1)` you posted, the `someAsynchronousCallback1` is never getting executed at all.

Comment: Now that you've updated the code, the text of the question doesn't fit to it. There's no `result` and no `asynchronousCallback1` any more.

Comment: @Bergi Does it make more sense now?

Comment: @tonitone120 much, much better, I've voted to reopen it. I suggested that you look at a Promise polyfill to see how it works.

Comment: @Bergi Do you think it's worthy of re-open now?

Comment: I'd probably now close it as a duplicate of [Is the Promise constructor callback executed asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29963129/1048572) - there are actually no microtasks involved in this code snippet, only the `setTimeout` macrotask.

Comment: And I'm not sure about the "*how can something that was once on the call-stack have its value changed by an entirely different function that appears later on the call-stack?*" remark. It's the same as in a mundane `const obj = {value: null}; setTimeout(() => { obj.value = 'result!'; })`, just that `resolve` is modifying internals of the promise object instead of modifying a normal object property.

Comment: @Bergi You're right that is what I'm getting at. Sorry this question took so long to finalise. What do you think of it now if you wouldn't mind sparing your thought?

Comment: Where is `resolve("done!")` in the code snippet?

Comment: @tonitone120 Now it's just [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/1048572). The timeout is not even relevant for that, you also have no `color` on the *call stack* in `let g; function f(){ const color = 'red'; g = () => console.log(red); } f(); g();`

Comment: @Bergi I'm observing, what seems to me, strange behaviour and I'm guessing closures have something to do with it. I'm sure you could confirm to me it's something to do with closures or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Yes, this is plain closures behaviour, nothing strange about it.

Comment: @Bergi Okay, thank-you